# Laravel route to add in pivot table works function in model with controller not

Tags: php, laravel

Route:

```
   Route::get('/addItemToOrder/{orderId}/{itemId}/{qt}', function ($orderId, $itemId, $qt) {
    $order = Order::find($orderId);
    $item = Item::find($itemId);
    $order->items()->attach($item, ['qt' => $qt]);
});
```

WORKS Fine.

Pivot model

```
class ItemOrder extends Pivot
{
    //

    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id',
        'item_id',
        'qt'
    ];

    static public function create($orderId, $itemId, $qt)
    {
        $order = Order::find($orderId);
        $item = Item::find($itemId);
        $order->items()->attach($item, ['qt' => $qt]);
    }
```

Controller

```
class ItemOrderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //

        $itemOrders = ItemOrder::all();
        return view('itemOrder.index', compact('itemOrders'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        $items = Item::pluck('name', 'id');
        $orders = Order::pluck( 'account_id', 'id');
        $qt = 0;
        return view('itemOrder.create', compact('items', 'orders', 'qt'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(ItemOrdersRequest $request)
    {
        //

        ItemOrder::create($request->all());
        return redirect('/itemOrder');
    }
```

Request

```
    class ItemOrdersRequest extends FormRequest
       {
        /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
            'order_id'=>'required',
            'item_id'=>'required',
            'qt'=>'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Blade create

```
   {!! Form::open(['action' =>'App\Http\Controllers\ItemOrderController@store', 'method' => 'post', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

    {!! form::label('order_id', 'Order_id: ') !!}
    {!! form::select('order_id',$orders) !!}

    {!! form::label('item_id', 'Item_id: ') !!}
    {!! form::select('item_id',$items, null) !!}

    {!! form::label('quantity', 'Quantity: ') !!}
    {!! form::number('qt',$qt) !!}

    {!! form::submit('Add Item to Order') !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Error is

> Too few arguments to function App\Models\ItemOrder::create(), 1 passed
> in
> C:\Users\ma\ecom-laravel\app\Http\Controllers\ItemOrderController.php
> on line 50 and exactly 3 expected

Laravel Framework 8.38.0

Help please. Thank you.

Comment: This is pure PHP mate, use a good IDE as it will automatically highlight you are doing something wrong... As a user already replied to you, you are sending only an array as the first parameter, when it needs 3 parameters...

Comment: ItemOrder::create($request->all()); this method is expecting 3 params as you defined it in the model class (create($orderId, $itemId, $qt)). Instead pass $request->all() pass it the three separated by comma params.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `$request->all()` you have to pass **3 params** to  `ItemOrder::create`.

You have defined `create` method in your model. Better rename to a different name to avoid conflicts between Laravel's default method names.

```php
public function store(ItemOrdersRequest $request)
{
    ItemOrder::create($request->order_id,$request->item_id,$request->qt);

    return redirect('/itemOrder');
}
```

Comment: @matiaslauriti.Thanks for taking precious time to modify mistakes  in answer.